# Dynamic Data Binding?

Tags: xpages

I have several fields on my Notes Document

FieldA_1
FieldA_2
FieldA_3
FieldA_4

FieldB_1
FieldB_2
FieldB_3
FieldB_4

On a composite control I have 2 edit boxes
FieldA
FieldB

I have a compositeData.ATM_NUM defined a custom control that is a drop down list with the values 1,2,3,4.

How do I bind the edit boxes on my control to their corresponding document fields using the composite data available?

For example, I wanted to do something like:
"FieldA_"+ compositeData.ATM_NUM.

I tried the javascript solution in this thread:

[Binding an edit box within a custom control to a form field programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992506/binding-an-edit-box-within-a-custom-control-to-a-form-field-programatically)

But it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following as value for e.g. field A:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document['FieldA'+compositeData.ATM_NUM]}" />
```

You could also extend the property of the custom control to include the whole field name (and thereby transfer e.g. "FieldA_1" to the custom control). Then you should be able to do the following:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document[compositeData.fieldName]}" />
```

Comment: You might also want to check out this explanation of the technique Per is recommending: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719778/xpages-more-fields-unlimited-at-the-click-of-a-button/9720793#9720793

Comment: I tried value="#{document1[CMBUExistTermID+compositeData.ATM_NUM]}"  but I got an error.  I am going to try the field thing but would rather avoid it if I can.   I'd like to figure out how to do it with just my composite "number" field.

Comment: Also tried value="#{document1['CMBUExistTermID' + '4']}"  which gives an error An exception occured trying to convert String "CMBUExistTermID" to type "java.lang.Double"  but alue="#{document1['CMBUExistTermID4']}" works fine.

Comment: is ATM_NUM a number? then you probably need to convert to a string: value="#{document1[CMBUExistTermID+compositeData.ATM_NUM.toString()]}"

Comment: No ATM_NUM is a string.  Besides even value="#{document1['CMBUExistTermID' + '4']}"   gives me that double exception and it should not.

Comment: Did you try this (with quotes around the first part of the field name)?: value="#{document1['CMBUExistTermID'+compositeData.ATM_NUM]}"

Comment: Yes that is basically what I posted above.  value="#{document1['CMBUExistTermID' + '4']}"    I really wish these comments were easier to read, they are way to crowded.   Easy to miss something.

Comment: Yes, but please try with value="#{document1['CMBUExistTermID'+compositeData.ATM_NUM]}" because I suspect that the test with '4' tries to convert the first string to a double.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9429/discussion-between-bruce-stemplewski-and-per-henrik-lausten)

Comment: Read/write bindings must be plain EL, which has a far more restrictive syntax than SSJS. If you wrap the field in a panel, you can define a dataContext, set its value to whatever expression you want to evaluate the field name, then pass its var to the data source in the field binding. Alternatively, you can wrap it in a Custom Control that accepts the field name as a parameter, then reference the compositeData in the field binding.

Answer (score 6):

An example for data binding for a custom control is this:

Create a custom control, add 2 custom properties: BindTo (String), canEdit (Boolean). Quite often you have the need to have a field readonly based on the state of your business logic rather than the fact that the rest is in edit mode.

```
 <xp:listBox id="listBox1"
        rendered="#{compositeData.canEdit}">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.BindTo+"}"}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="red"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="blue"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="green"></xp:selectItem>
 </xp:listBox>
 <xp:text id="textForListbox"
        rendered="#{!compositeData.canEdit}">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.BindTo+"}"}]]></xp:this.value>
 </xp:text>
```

The advantage of this approach (using `${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.BindTo+"}"}`) is that you can bind that control to anything: a document, a scope variable, a bean etc.

Comment: cheers. first time I've seen how to do dynamic binding to something other than a document.  very useful

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to the time that compositeData is ready for your use. At the start it evaluates to "0" when your custom control is ready.

Try this:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" 
           value="${javascript:'#{document1.SomeField'+compositeData.SomeParam+'}'}">
</xp:inputText>
```

It's important to use "$" sign there. It will create a binding to SomeField1, SomeField2 and so forth depending on SomeParam.

Comment: Thanks Serdar, I tried that but it did not work.   No errors or anything just did not populate the field as expected.   Here is the actual formula I used. value="${javascript:'#{document1.CMBUAction'+compositeData.ATM_NUM+'}'}">

Comment: OK, where is the document1 defined? Inside CC or in the XPage?

Comment: I spoke too soon.  It is working perfectly.   What is the purpose of the $?   Is any of this documented anywhere?

Comment: $ implies that the inside script will be calculated once in the load phase. If you don't use $, the returning statement will not be evaluated as EL. I have used this for dynamic fields. In my case, a repeat control was creating Field1, Field2 like bindings for a dynamic questionnaire where number of questions were preconfigured.