# How to get Image uploading for Rich Text control within a repeat control to work

Tags: xpages

Using 8.5.3 UP1 with the Hotfix for the multi-rich text control issue.

I am dynamically binding rich text controls that are within a custom control wrapped in a repeat control. The rich text controls render just fine, except that the image upload functionality does not work. If I click on the image upload, choose a file, and then click send to server, the image apparently never makes it there.

Here is my code:

The Repeat Control:

```
<xp:repeat id="rptSections" rows="99" repeatControls="false"
    var="sections" indexVar="rptIndex" value="#{javascript:2}">
    <xc:ccDynamicSections_2 rptIndex="#{javascript:rptIndex}">
        <xc:this.fieldName><![CDATA[#{javascript:"contentRT"+rptIndex}]]></xc:this.fieldName>
    </xc:ccDynamicSections_2>       
</xp:repeat>
```

The custom control:

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1" value="#{document1[compositeData.fieldName]}" >   
</xp:inputRichText>
```

I'm pretty sure if I can find a way to bind the rich text controls at run time I can make this work. I tried to do this and it appears to work on the page but when I go to save the document I get a error such like "Could not save the document NEW_79 NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled"

Bind after page load attempt:

```
<xp:repeat id="rptSections" rows="99" repeatControls="false"
    var="sections" indexVar="rptIndex" value="#{javascript:2}">

    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var application = facesContext.getApplication();var scopedField = 'content'+rptIndex;var valueBinding = application.createValueBinding( '#{document1.' + scopedField + '}');getComponent("inputRichText1").setValueBinding('value', valueBinding );"test"+rptIndex}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>

    <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"></xp:inputRichText>
</xp:repeat>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For dynamic binding, I have just answered this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913331/dynamic-data-binding/9915444#9915444

Comment: I've left the office but I'll give this a try first thing Monday. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried using a $ instead of # before the javascript and it doesn't work with that. I get an error -it can't reference rptIndex. I've updated my code to show my last attempt.Here is the code I tried with the $: `<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:var application = facesContext.getApplication();
var scopedField = 'content'+rptIndex;
var valueBinding = application.createValueBinding( '#{document1.' + scopedField + '}');
getComponent("inputRichText1").setValueBinding('value', valueBinding );
"test"+rptIndex}]]></xp:this.value>
  </xp:text>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set repeatControls to true. Or else it will fail to correctly bind to your datasource. See [this page](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2011/03/repeatcontrols-troubles-solution.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20dontpanic82%20%28DontPanic%20-%20a%20blog%20about%20Lotus%20Notes%20/%20Domino%29) too.

Comment: Thanks!! That did it! Oddly when I first tried it, it didn't appear to work and then later it did? Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Code: `<xp:repeat id="rptSections" rows="99" repeatControls="true"
  var="sections" indexVar="rptIndex" value="#{javascript:2}">
  <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var application = facesContext.getApplication();
var scopedField = 'content'+rptIndex;
var valueBinding = application.createValueBinding( '#{document1.' + scopedField + '}');
getComponent("inputRichText1").setValueBinding('value', valueBinding );
"test"+rptIndex}]]></xp:this.value>
  </xp:text>
  <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"></xp:inputRichText>
 </xp:repeat>`