# Where is com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite documented?

Tags: xpages

Can anyone tell me where com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite is documented?  I searched in the help file for UIIncludeComposite but found nothing.

There is only one brief mention of it in Mastering xPages.

com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite is the class for the object returned by getComponent when calling getComponent for a custom control.

In fact where is anything documented?  I think the single biggest frustration as a newbie xPage programmer is the lack of documentation or where to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java class is documented in the Javadoc available at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Domino_Designer_Extensibility_APIs_Javadoc_8.5.3 which points to this page for the specific class:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/component/UIIncludeComposite.html

General documentation for Upgrade Pack 1 and Extension Library is available here:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Designer%20XPages%20Extension%20Library

Comment: Wow thanks much for the links! I don't have a lot of experience with javadocs.   How would I search for say getChildren method?  Tell you what I was hoping to find.  I was hoping to see a way to get to the components (an edit box) within a specific control (I have the same control on the xpage more than once).

Comment: I have added a comment to your question on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001442/getting-a-field-value-from-a-custom-control-when-there-are-multiple-instances-of