# Custom Property in Repeat control stopped working

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a strange bug that is reproducible but i cant find out whats causing it.
If i call this xpage i get the following error message:

Error while executing JavaScript computed expression

'fieldname' not found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="Request"></xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
<xp:repeat rows="999" var="fieldname">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"myfieldname"}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xc:Widgets_Field
        field_datasource="#{javascript:currentDocument}"
        field_name="#{javascript:fieldname}">
    </xc:Widgets_Field>
</xp:repeat>
```

I have tried to empty the cc but without any success. The only thing thats working is when i am either hardcoding the property field_name or when i set the repeat control to "create controls at page creation"

I am absolutely sure that code was working before but i cant find out whats causing the error message. Can you please give it a try and let me know if you also have the same problem.

Attached please see stack trace

```
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)
com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.getBindingValue(ExpressionEvaluatorImpl.java:151)
xsp.Widgets_005fField$Widgets_005fFieldPage.createInputText4(Widgets_005fField.java:776)
xsp.Widgets_005fField$Widgets_005fFieldPage.createComponent(Widgets_005fField.java:142)
com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.buildComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:265)
com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:115)
com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: I answered the question. If you paste problematic bindings within the custom control, I can try to find a workaround.

Comment: What's the code of your CC? Especially of the *InputText4* component?

Comment: The cc is completely empty

Comment: No, it is not. Maybe in your DDE, but the compiled code inside the database is still there.

Comment: `xsp.Widgets_005fField$Widgets_005fFieldPage.createInputText4(Widgets_005fField.java:776)` line shows that compiled page is not the same as what you saw. Sometimes, if something wrong in the XSP markup (unclosed tag, illegal value, etc.) it does not compile. Create another empty CC with a different name and try in that way.

Comment: Thanks you were right. I had to clean and rebuild again to get an empty one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the custom control, if you use wrong binding that should be known at the page load, it throws such an error. For instance if your custom control contains a "loaded" attribute like:

```
<xp:text
  loaded="${compositeData.field_name}">
```

That will throw such an error. That's why it works with "create controls at page creation" setting.

Update: If you are going to use dynamic binding within the custom control, see my answer at this question:

[Dynamic Data Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913331/dynamic-data-binding/9915444#9915444)

Comment: that would make sense but the problem is that the CC is completely empty

Comment: What are your property types? Also, is there any event or property defined within the cc?

Comment: field_datasource is of type object the rest is a string

Comment: On your error stack, there seems like a input field in the custom control. Can you clean the project?

Comment: the first thing i tried was cleaning the project and restarting the  server.