# How to send a document data souce to a custom control in XPages?

Tags: xpages, custom-controls, el, composite

I have this computed text bound to a the body field using EL

```
 <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{doc.Body}"></xp:text>
```

Now I need to store this computedField in a Custom Control and send in the doc? What property definition should I use, and how do I reference the compositeData to the Body field in the cc

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom property on your Custom Control called `dataSource` and set the type to `com.ibm.xsp.model.DataSource`

Create a second custom property called `computedFieldName` and set it's type to `string`

In the computed field in the custom control set the value like

`value="#{compositeData.dataSource[compositeData.computedFieldName]}"`

When using the custom control just set the custom properties like:

`computedFieldName="Body"
 dataSource="#{doc}"`

Comment: I might be missing something.  Why not skip the property definition entirely and in the CC and just continue to bind the computed field to the named datasource defined on the XPage, simply #{doc.Body}.

Comment: @PaulDella-Nebbia Doing it the way I've outlined means the custom control is more reusable.  It can handle fields with different names and different data sources too.  There is a way to write this to allow the custom control to accept anything, not just a document as the data source e.g. a bean.  But the details of that method escape me at the minute.

Comment: My example was simplified for Stack overflow, The real scenario contain file upload control used in many different XPages that have different data source names

Comment: I've found the dynamic binding thing I'd mentioned in my earlier comment.  See Stephan Wissel's answer for an even more dynamic way of binding data: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19309383/4193769

Comment: Well that make perfect sense then.